# Change path for websql database and access it from a different location on the server (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, database, apache, path, web-sql

I am running apache on ubuntu linux, and I would like to be able for my website to access the websql database.

How might I access it from the same Javascript in two webpages (Namely get data from **index.html** and access it in **mylist.html**)

Here is my code for now without retrieving data:

```js
var db = openDatabase('articles', '1.0', 'Saved Articles', 2 * 1024 * 1024); 

db.transaction(function (tx) {   
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ARTICLES (id unique, log)');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ARTICLES (id, article) VALUES ('+ac.parentNode.innerHTML+')'); 
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Working on it....